# Why are these strings not equal?

Tags: string-manipulation

```
let os = system('uname -o')
function Strcmp(str1, str2)
    if a:str1 < a:str2
        return -1
    elseif a:str1 == a:str2
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    endif
endfunction

echo Strcmp(os,"Android")
```

I do not know why does it return 1 when `os` stores `Android`

I tried `echo os` and it printed `Android`, still this function returns `1`

Comment: are you sure `os` is not `Android\n`?

Comment: Whenever encountering situations like this (in any language) it's always good to run the strings through a length function (e.g. `strlen()`) and/or, if available, a function that makes control characters visible like Vim's `strtrans()` which in this case will probably show `Android^@`. Then you'll have a better chance of figuring out why the difference exists.

Comment: Also, FYI, it's best to try to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your example is reducible to something like `if system('uname -o') !=# "Android" | echo 'No match!' | endif`. In the process of reducing things you might even figure out what's going on. Welcome to Vi&Vim SE.

Answer (score 1):

The `system()` function captures the full output of the command; in practice this almost always ends with a newline (`\n`); almost all Unix commands end with this as the last character.

This is common gotcha with `system()`. You can use the `trim()` function to remove any leading or trailing whitespace:

```
let os = trim(system('uname -o'))
```

Or you can use string slicing to remove the last byte:

```
let os = system('uname -o')[:-2]
```